# OPL how to iterate each element in a set to trait in execute field

Tags: opl

i want to traite the datas in execute, and I have to iterate elements in a {string} Donnnes defined before. That looks like:

```
{string} Donnnes = ...;
execute{
//how can i iterate each element in set to trait
    for(){//please help me to fill all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found it:

```
{string} Donnes = ...;
range indices = 0..card(Donnes);
execute{
//how can i iterate each element in set to trait
    for(var i in indices){//please help me to fill all
       var ele = Opl.item(donnes,i);
       //for traiting each ele......
    }
}
```